# How to make adaptive UI in Windows 10?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-10, uwp

I am trying to migrate my old app to Windows 10 and I am facing an issue with Grid. I created a Grid in XAML page with WebView and ListView inside it in 2 different rows. Now problem is that it appears fine in Local Machine(Laptop) but when I check the same in Windows Phone, it doesn't look good(image, text looks very large). Please find my XAML code and DataTemplate for ListView below. I am aware that RelativePanel will save my day, but can anyone update my code and suggest me so that I can use the same on each page as my app uses ListView inside Grid very often.

**XAML CODE**

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="{StaticResource AppBackGroundColor}">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <WebView Grid.Row="0"
             x:Name="webView"
             DefaultBackgroundColor="#388941"
             IsHitTestVisible="False"/>
    <ListView x:Name="loginandRegisterOptionslist"
             Margin="0,10,0,0"
             Grid.Row="1"
             ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
             ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource GenericListViewContainerStyle}"
             ItemTemplate="{StaticResource WelcomePageListItemTemplate}"
             VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
             SelectionMode="Single"
             />
</Grid>
```

**Data Template for above ListView**

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="WelcomePageListItemTemplate">

        <Grid Margin="0,2,0,2"
          Background="White">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <Image Width="80"
               Height="60"
               Name="img1"
               Stretch="Uniform"
               Margin="4,0,4,0"
               Grid.Column="0"
               Source="{Binding IMAGE_URL}"></Image>

            <StackPanel Grid.Column="1"
                    Margin="0,8,0,8">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding TITLE}"
                       Margin="2"
                       Style="{StaticResource HeaderContentStyle}" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding VALUE}"
                       Margin="2"
                       Style="{StaticResource DescriptionContentStyle}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>

</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: What exactly is your issue? Image and texts are too large on mobile and we shall find out why?

Comment: yes that's my issue. I have not used above code.

Comment: I'm not a fan of down-voting questions but when I read something like "can anyone update my code" it makes me think they haven't tried anything and want someone to do their work. Especially when you can copy/paste the question title into google and find a number of articles that teach & explain how to do it...

Comment: Chris. I tried using Relative Panel and Google didn't me answer which I am looking for that's why I posted the Question here. If you don't know the answer then don't comment also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some solutions that you might want to try out:

- Put your datatemplace inside an User Control, use [Adaptive Trigger](http://www.wintellect.com/devcenter/jprosise/using-adaptivetrigger-to-build-adaptive-uis-in-windows-10) to custom the size of image and text according to difference screen sizes.
- Use difference XAML View for difference device families
- When launching the app, detect the device family, set the correct value for size binding base on that information

Comment: I also got the first option from Google search, but I can't use that as I have many ListView on different pages. Can you add any useful links for Solution 2 and 3?

Comment: for 2nd solution, you can find more detail here http://igrali.com/2015/08/02/three-ways-to-set-specific-devicefamily-xaml-views-in-uwp/


3rd one: add properties ImageWidth and ImageHeight to the object used in listview. Set them to appropriate value based on device family. Bind them to Width / Height property of Image. Same principle apply for the text's FontSize